# Pass *args to string.format in Python?

Tags: python, logging, args

Is it possible to pass *args to string.format? I have the following function:

```
@classmethod
def info(cls, component, msg, *args):
    """Log an info message"""
    cls.__log(cls.Level.INFO, component, msg, args)

@classmethod
def __log(cls, level, component, msg, *args):
    """Log a message at the requested level"""
    logging.getLogger("local").log(level, " - ".join([component, msg.format(args)]))
```

When I try unit test it with LogCapture I get the following:

```
def test_logWithArgs(self):
    Logger.level(Logger.Level.INFO)
    with LogCapture(level=Logger.Level.INFO) as lc:
        Logger.info("MyComponent", "{0}", "TestArg")
        lc.check(("local", "INFO", "MyComponent - TestArg"))


AssertionError: Sequence not as expected:

same:
()

first:
(('local', 'INFO', 'MyComponent - TestArg'),)

second:
(('local', 'INFO', "MyComponent - (('TestArg',),)"),)
```

Comment: I think you've got your answer - but I should refer you to the logging.Formatter facility

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you want to do is

```
msg.format(*args)
```

Comment: This results in the following `(('local', 'INFO', "MyComponent - ('TestArg',)"),)`

Comment: You have to change it info() too: `cls.__log(cls.Level.INFO, component, msg, *args)`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be done by unpacking like this:

```
>>> a = (1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> "{0}{1}{2}{3}".format(*a)
'1234'
```