# String formatting with *args

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I looked at the following few posts and wasn't quite able to figure out what I want to do.

[python - How to format variable number of arguments into a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391059/python-how-to-format-variable-number-of-arguments-into-a-string)

[Pass *args to string.format in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197072/pass-args-to-string-format-in-python)

What I want to do is simple. Given some array of variable length I want to be able to print all the arguments individually. That is, I want

`print('{} {} ...'.format(*arg))`

Obviously I won't be able to predict how many {} I will need before hand and I tried `len(x)*'{}'` which didn't yield what I wanted. If I leave that out then I only get the first argument. What is the way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so why not just:

```
print(" ".join(map(str,args)))
```

which does the same thing as `{} {} ...` in format

Answer (score 2):

Why use a format string at all?  `print` can do this for you:

```
print(*arg)
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre "Given some array of variable length I want to be able to print all the arguments individually."  Maybe their actual requirements call for more complexity, but from what's here, this should be sufficient.

Comment: yeah, anyway, this is a nice feature of `print`, we cannot publiciez that enough